# set the overflow:auto with height 100%

Tags: css

In my page, I have an element which has a height of 100% based on its parent; however, I want this element to auto scroll vertically when necessary. This is [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/qng67/).

I can not make it.

I have added the following css:

```
height:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

In fact, what I want is to make sure that the `.content` is always inside the `.container`. Like this:

[image: pic.]

(BTW, in the above image, I use the `max-height:400px` which should be avoided since the maximum height of it should be based on the height of `.container`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is close to the solution you are looking for, though you may need to adjust the padding and such for a more aesthetically pleasing look: http://jsfiddle.net/GJ5yM/

New CSS:

```
    .content{
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .windowcontent{
        background-color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        max-height:100%;
        position:relative;
        overflow-y:auto;
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to set `height:100%` to `.content` since I want the size of the `.content` will resize according to the contents inside it. Then in your exmaple,the `.content` always take the whole height.

Comment: In fact I have tried your solution before I post this question,however I want the `.windowContent` scroll rather than `.content`

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, that my not end up being possible. You may need to rethink the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/siyakunde/qng67/1/
Is this what you want??

I have given

```
max-height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
```

to content.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/CjV6k/1/

The CSS:

```
#scrollFrameWrap { 
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #000; 
  border-radius: 8px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 0 #fff inset;
  padding: 3px 10px 10px;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}
#parentElement {
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
#scrollFrame {
  width: 380px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="scrollFrameWrap">
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <div id="parentElement">
    <div id="scrollFrame">
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
      <p>This is a sentence, hope you like it.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See if that helps

Comment: Not the same as my post,since `scrollFrameWrap` should have a fixed height(which will be changed)

Answer (score -3):

set only

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

and set height whatever u want.